# React Native -- .Map() items in Child won't rerender after Child event handler updates Parent's state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-component

In my project, while looping through a datafile with the `.map()` function, I'm passing down a function (`updatestate`) from the Parent Component, `App`, to the Child, `Main`, that allows the Child to call `.setState()` and append to the array in the Parent state.

But, when I call this function to set Parent's state, **the mapped section** -- **`{contents}`** -- **won't rerender unless I tap the screen again.**

Any ideas? Am I missing some binding or need to do some componentDidMount or anything? I've tried adding `this.forceUpdate()` inside the eventHandler but the **mapped `{contents}` section ** still won't render automatically.

```
const RootStack = StackNavigator(
  {
    Main: {
      screen: Main}
  }
);

export default class App extends Component<{}> {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        favoritesList: []
      };
    }

  updateArr=(itemname, url)=>{this.setState({ favoritesList: [...this.state.favoritesList, {"item_name":itemname, "url":url}]})};

  render() {
      return <RootStack screenProps={{appstate: this.state,
                                    updatestate: this.updateArr}}
      />;
    }
  }

class Main extends React.Component {

  render() {
    var updatestate = this.props.screenProps.updatestate;

    //collection is the data (local JSON) i'm looping thru via .map in Main Component

    const contents = collection.map((item, index) => {
        return (
            <Card key={index}
                  onSwipedRight={() => {updatestate(item.item_name,item.url)}}
            >
              <View> //THIS and anything after <Card> doesn't render for the next card automatically if I do 'onSwipedRight'
                <Image
                    source={{uri: item.url}} />
               </View>
            </Card>
        )
      },this);

      return (
      <View>
            <CardStack>

              {contents} //THIS IS THE PART THAT WON'T AUTO-RERENDER AFTER THE EVENT HANDLER THAT SETS THE PARENT'S STATE

            </CardStack>
      </View>
        );
    }
}
```

To make sure it's not an issue with the event handler, I added in a function that doesn't set the state of the parent, and had `<Card>` call that on the event handler -- it works perfectly and the child component `<Card>` renders perfectly. It seems that it's the `updatestate` function passed down from the parent to the child that acts to call `.setState()` upstream that for some reason is causing the Child to not render/not finish rendering the **mapped `{contents}`** after the event handler.

```
class Main extends React.Component {
  render() {

    var updatestate = this.props.screenProps.updatestate;

    var newfunc = (a, b) => {console.log('a:', a, 'b:', b)};

      const contents = collection.map((item, index) => {
        return (
            <Card key={index}
                  newfunc(item.item_name,item.item_name);}}
                  // onSwipedRight={() => {updatestate(item.item_name,item.url); }}
                  >
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try rewriting your setState like so

```js
import { InteractionManager } from "react-native";

updateArr = (itemname, url) => {
  InteractionManager.runAfterInteractions(() => {
    this.setState( prevState => ({
      favoritesList: [...prevState.favoritesList, {       "item_name":itemname, "url":url } ]
    });
  });
  
}

// add this line to your parent component constructor()
this.updateArr = this.updateArr.bind(this);
```

In addition I suggest you change your React.Component to React.PureComponent instead it will handle the shallow equal of your state changes for you and increate performance.
for reference [React.Component vs React.PureComponent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41340697/react-component-vs-react-purecomponent)

Comment: :( still no luck with that suggestion -- parent's state is updating properly (as it was before as well), but after the event of `onSwipedRight` the mapped part, `{contents}` is not rendering.

Comment: I wonder if the animation of the swipe is not allowing the state to update properly.

try wrapping the setState inside the updateArr with
InteractionManager.runAfterInteractions(() => {
       this.setState( ... )
})

also in your App (parent component) add this line to the constructor
this.updateArr = this. updateArr.bind(this);

Comment: Ooh that sounds like it could potentially be it! I'm having some issues implementing your suggestions in your last comment though from this format -- could you add it onto your answer in code form? much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Try not using `index` as `key`. Meaningful key values help the engine figure out what needs to be redrawn.

In your case, I'd suggest `key={item.url}` as a first go.

https://medium.com/@robinpokorny/index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern-e0349aece318