# React - will not re render on state change

Tags: reactjs

I'm all new to react.
Why does my page not re render on mouse over and mouse out when my state changes? If I look at `console.log`, I can see the state changes. But I can't get this to work. Here is my code:

```
export default class Nav extends React.PureComponent {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.navLevelOneId = '';

    this.state = {
      showSubMenu: []
    };
  }

  // Mouse over function
  handleHover = (id,event) => {
    let showSubMenu=this.state.showSubMenu;
    showSubMenu[id]=!showSubMenu[id]
    this.setState({showSubMenu: showSubMenu}, () => {
      console.log(this.state.showSubMenu);  
    });
  }

  render() {

    return (

          <div ref="megaMenu" className="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
            <div className="container">
              <div className="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" className="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                  <span className="icon-bar"></span>
                  <span className="icon-bar"></span>
                  <span className="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
              </div>
              <div className="navbar-collapse collapse">
                      <ul className="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li onMouseOver={this.handleHover.bind(this,0)} onMouseOut={this.handleHover.bind(this,0)}>
                                  <a>Home</a>
                                </li>
                        <li className="dropdown menu-large" onMouseOver={this.handleHover.bind(this,1)} onMouseOut={this.handleHover.bind(this,1)}>
                    <a className="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Product Listing</a>

                                    <ul className={"dropdown-menu megamenu row " + this.state.showSubMenu[1]}>
                      <li>
                        <div className="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
                          <a href="" className="thumbnail">
                                  <img src="http://placehold.it/150x120" alt="test" />
                          </a>
                        </div>
                        <div className="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
                              <a href="" className="thumbnail">
                                  <img src="http://placehold.it/150x120" alt="test" />
                          </a>
                        </div>
                        <div className="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
                              <a href="" className="thumbnail">
                                  <img src="http://placehold.it/150x120" alt="test" />
                          </a>
                        </div>
                        <div className="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
                          <a href="" className="thumbnail">
                                  <img src="http://placehold.it/150x120" alt="test" />
                          </a>
                          </div>
                              </li>
                    </ul>

                  </li>

                        <li className="dropdown menu-large" onMouseOver={this.handleHover.bind(this,2)} onMouseOut={this.handleHover.bind(this,2)}>
                            <a className="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Categories</a>

                                    <ul className={"dropdown-menu megamenu row " + this.state.showSubMenu[2]}>
                      <li>
                        <div className="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
                          <a href="" className="thumbnail">
                                  <img src="http://placehold.it/150x120" alt="test" />
                          </a>
                        </div>
                        <div className="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
                              <a href="" className="thumbnail">
                                  <img src="http://placehold.it/150x120" alt="test" />
                          </a>
                        </div>
                        <div className="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
                              <a href="" className="thumbnail">
                                  <img src="http://placehold.it/150x120" alt="test" />
                          </a>
                        </div>
                        <div className="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
                          <a href="" className="thumbnail">
                                  <img src="http://placehold.it/150x120" alt="test" />
                          </a>
                          </div>
                              </li>
                    </ul>

                        </li>
                  </ul>
                  </div>
            </div>
          </div>


            );

      }

    }
```

Comment: Have you tried passing a callback to these events? `() => this.handleHover` instead? Also, I am not sure if you want to bind handleHover because it is an arrow function and arrow functions have no idea of an `Object` and keyword `this`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out [the difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41340697/react-component-vs-react-purecomponent) between using `Component` and `PureComponent`.

Briefly, `PureComponent` performs a shallow comparison on state change. That means that it compares only references for state objects and arrays (in your case `this.state.showSubMenu` is an array and it's reference doesn't change so React won't force a rerender there)