# How to fire change in component from other component?

Tags: reactjs

I've tried make project with listing of cafes and markers in Google MAP their locations.

Idea is to click on place to select cafe and - get selcted appropriate markers and vice versa (click marker - get focused appropriate cafe in listing)

I have hierarhy of nested components like:

```
< App>:
   <List>
     <place1>
     <place2>
     ....
     <place10>
   </List>
   <Map>
    <marker of place1/>
    <marker of place2/>
   ...
   <marker of place10/>
  </Map>
</App>
```

I can make simple way just keep information which cafe selected in variable inside **State** of top parent  - **App**.

But I dont want to fire rendering all this whole tree of components - its a lot work for browser.

I can keep **focused** value inside state of each child components **placeX** and **markerX**. So When I click some **placeX** is toggle to **focused:true** and send to next previous component to **focused:false** through function in parent- **List**. So - its just 2 child components going to re-render.

But how to fire changes in child components -  in next branch:  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But I dont want to fire rendering all this whole tree of components - its a lot work for browser.

You just need to pass proper properties to each component and use `extends React.PureComponent` to ensure it doesn't re-render component if nothing has been changed in props.

Imagine you have `focused` property in your App State which equals to `X`, which is actually focused. So you shouldn't pass it roughly to all components (as they will re-render each focus change), but you should calculate proper property, i.e. `isFocused = state.focused === X`.

Then it will re-render two components - the one which is focused next and the one which was focused before.

**EDIT**:

class App

```
...
updateFocus(x) {
  this.updateState('focused', x)
}

render() {
  const focused = this.state.focused;
  <Map focused={focused} updateFocus={updateFocus} ... />
}
```

class Map

```
...
render() {
  const {focused, updateFocus} = this.props;

  return <div>
    {this.renderMarkerItem(x, focused, updateFocus)}
  </div>
}

renderMarkerItem(x, focused, updateFocus) {
  const isFocused = focused === x;
  return <Marker x={x} focused={focused} updateFocus={updateFocus}>
}
...
```

[React.PureComponent vs React.Component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41340697/react-component-vs-react-purecomponent#43936258)

Comment: @KD Please consider marking the response as `Accepted` (Checkmark on the left) if it fixes your issue.

Comment: Unfortunatelly its doesnt work. 

I used **extends React.PureComponent** in all class components  instead of **extend React.Component**.  
I made TopParent class property **isFocused** and function **window.updateFocus(x){this.isFocused=x}** that call in deep nested child component onClick event. 

So ... TopParent property **isFocused** get value from grand children, but its doesnt fire re-render appropriate childrens.

Comment: Sorry! I just got research - I have to fire forceUpdate()

Comment: @KD `forceUpdate()` although it is noted in the link I added this is not necessary (`shallowCompare` should work in your case perfectly). I bet the issue is in a different place. How are you passing the `isFocused` property to nested components?

Comment: @KD Please check the sketch I added in the answer.