# React.PureComponent and childs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props, react-component, rerender

Someone please explain me this last paragraph of the React documentation with a simple example, it's about React.PureComponent , all the examples I've seen are advanced and I'm just starting to know this concept and I can't see exactly what it refers to. **Precisely the point that children should also be "pure"**.
To the best of my knowledge, **I believe that this statement is over-stated, because if the father does not re-render himself, then neither do the children**, or, is there something that escapes me and I cannot visualize it? That is why I need a simple example, I already looked at all the similar questions here but they are advanced examples and do not cover what I am looking for.

"*Furthermore, React.PureComponent's shouldComponentUpdate() skips prop updates for the whole component subtree. **Make sure all the children components are also "pure"***"

Comment: See also https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/10610.

Comment: If it is somewhat ambiguous, what I deduce in my humble opinion, is that the React documentation says it simply to REAFFIRM that the PureComponent itself will be Pure, the children have a "separate" treaty, you decide if you make them pure or not, that is, that the parent is pure does not make the children automatically pure, I think that's what the documentation means and that's why it warns that.

Comment: That's why I said in the question that I think it's redundant that statement in the documentation, but hopefully someone else will see this post and tell us what we're missing.

Answer (score 0):

I made something to play with.

I think the important part to realize, is that there is only one difference, it is the `shouldComponentUpdate` implementation on `PureComponent`.

I am also confused about `Make sure all the children components are also “pure”`. From my understanding, it is meant as a warning, as a guideline, not as an absolute don't. When you put a parent as PureComponent, all the childrens become impacted. But someone not used to `shouldComponentUpdate` (PureComponent) may be surprised by childrens behavior (not updating) when mixing both in the tree.

Take for example in the second snippet `this.state.quotes[0].text = "StackOverflow save the day";`. When using `Component` on both `<List/>` and `<ListElement/>`, any `setState` would update the view. But when using `PureComponent` on only `<List/>`, someone may expect `<ListElement/>` to update, but it won't.

Imagine that, that instead of writing `<List/>` as pure, and `<ListElement/>` as unpure, what they warn NOT to do. You would have written both as pure. Would you even think of doing something like `this.state.quotes[0].text = "StackOverflow save the day";` ? No you would start with `this.state.quotes[0] = {...}`. And then you would take a look at which component handle the data above, the `quotes` array, the component handling the array, is it pure ? Yes it is, then write `this.state = [{...}]` instead. You do this "recreating references/deep copy" until you find the first non-pure component. If you followed their advice, at the first non-pure component, you know there won't be any other stale reference blocking your rendering.

If using deep comparison, you would never have that issue. I am using hooks components, they are much more friendly. I recommend you skip class component and use hooks. In hooks to implement `shouldComponentUpdate` you use [React.memo](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo). Since **YOU decide how you compare props**, it becomes quite obvious that if you compare `previousList === newList` (shallow comparison), you will miss any update/add/delete on the list. And naturally you will do a deep comparison (use `deep-equal` lib or (avoid) `JSON.stringify(previousList) === JSON.stringify(newList)`. Note that `React.Memo` is better for another reason, it only handle props comparison, not both state and props comparison as PureComponent.

I don't think you need every children to use shallow comparison, if the component render fast enough, using `shouldComponentUpdate` (or `React.memo`) can make it worse (remember it is a performance optimization).

This bellow demonstrate the issues we can get with shallow props comparison (first snippet) and shallow state comparison (second snippet):

```
import { Component, PureComponent } from 'react';

interface Quote {
  author: string;
  text: string;
}

export class Playground extends Component {
  state = {
    quotes: [
      {
        author: 'Ambroise',
        text: 'I like React.'
      }
    ]
  }

  onClickOK () {
    this.setState({
      quotes: [
        {
          author: 'Ariel',
          text: 'Prefer VueJS.'
        }
      ]
    });
  }

  // https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactpurecomponent
  // React.PureComponent implements it with a shallow prop and state comparison
  // "prop comparison"
  onClickIssue() {
    if (window['dontMix']) {
      alert("Please don't mix on click issues. Reload page.")
      return;
    }
    window['dontMix'] = true;

    // This won't work if <List/> is a PureComponent
    // Note that we ALSO CHANGED the props for <ListElement/> here, different object, differents strings,
    // but <ListElement/> will NOT re-render, regardless of <ListElement/> being pure or not.
    const quotesUpdated = this.state.quotes;
    quotesUpdated.pop();
    quotesUpdated.push({
      author: 'Thomas',
      text: 'Prefer Angular.'
    });

    // Shallow props comparison, <List/> will compare array references
    // `quotesUpdated === this.state.quotes` and because it is true,
    // it will not re-render, or any of the childrens.
    //
    // The quote object is different, so <ListElement/>
    // would be expected to re-render.
    this.setState({
      quotes: quotesUpdated
    });
  }

  onClickIssue2() {
    if (window['dontMix']) {
      alert("Please don't mix on click issues. Reload page.")
      return;
    }
    window['dontMix'] = true;

    // This won't work if <ListElement/> is a PureComponent since the object in first index stay the same.
    // Since we recreate the array, <List/> will always re-render regardless of <List/> being pure.
    this.state.quotes[0].author = "Thomas";
    this.state.quotes[0].text = "Prefer Angular.";
    this.setState({
      quotes: [
        this.state.quotes[0],
      ]
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <section>
        <button onClick={this.onClickOK.bind(this)}>Get updated</button>
        <button onClick={this.onClickIssue.bind(this)}>Problem</button>
        <button onClick={this.onClickIssue2.bind(this)}>Problem2</button>
        <List quotes={this.state.quotes}/>
      </section>
    );
  }
}

// Change PureComponent to Component, no problem with shallow comparison anymore.
class List extends PureComponent<{ quotes: Quote[]; }>{
  render() {
    return (
      <ul>
        {
          this.props.quotes.map(
            (e, i) => <ListElement key={i} quote={e}/>
          )
        }
      </ul>
    );
  }
}

class ListElement extends PureComponent<{quote: Quote}> {
  render() {
    return (
      <li>
        <h3>{this.props.quote.author}</h3>
        <p>{this.props.quote.text}</p>
      </li>
    );
  }
}
```

A second snippet, focusing on the state shallow comparison, and also `<ListElement/>` start as a `Component` this time instead of a `PureComponent`.

```
import { Component, PureComponent } from 'react';

interface Quote {
  author: string;
  text: string;
}

export class Playground2 extends Component {
  state = {
    quotes: [
      {
        author: 'Ambroise',
        text: 'I like React.'
      }
    ]
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <section>
        <List quotes={this.state.quotes}/>
      </section>
    );
  }
}

// Note: Careful not to confuse state.quotes and props.quote
class List extends PureComponent<{ quotes: Quote[]; }> {
  state = {
    quotes: this.props.quotes
  };

  // https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactpurecomponent
  // React.PureComponent implements it with a shallow prop and state comparison
  // "state comparison"
  fail() {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.state.quotes.length; i++) {
      this.state.quotes.pop();
    }

    this.setState({
      quotes: this.state.quotes
    });
  }

  success() {
    // This will never work, because `previousState === newState` (both are this.state)
    // this.state.quotes = [];
    // this.setState(this.state);

    this.setState({
      quotes: []
    });
  }

  // It work if you change this class to Component
  changeChild() {
    // if you clicked another button reload the page to get initial state.
    if (this.state.quotes.length === 0) {
      alert("You clicked another button. Please reload page to test this one.");
    }

    // previously "I like React."
    this.state.quotes[0].text = "StackOverflow save the day";

    // NOTICE: Choose only one setState bellow, comment the others.

    // Won't work
    // this.setState({
    //   quotes: this.state.quotes
    // });

    // This will never work, because `previousState === newState` (both are this.state)
    // this.state.quotes = [this.state.quotes[0]];
    // this.setState(this.state);

    // Won't work
    this.setState(this.state);

    // This will work when <List/> is a PureComponent and <ListElement/> a Component,
    // both this.state and this.state.quotes are different
    // this.setState({
    //   quotes: [this.state.quotes[0]]
    // });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.fail.bind(this)}>Empty the list (FAIL if PureComponent)</button>
        <button onClick={this.success.bind(this)}>Empty the list (SUCCESS)</button>
        <button onClick={this.changeChild.bind(this)}>Change child (FAIL if PureComponent)</button>
        <ul>
          {
            this.state.quotes.map(
              (e, i) => <ListElement key={i} quote={e}/>
            )
          }
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

// ATTENTION: This one start as a Component this time, instead of a PureComponent
class ListElement extends Component<{quote: Quote}, {author: string}> {
  state = {
    author: this.props.quote.author,
  };

  // Yep this work.
  takeOwnership() {
    this.setState({
      author: "Constantin"
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <li>
        <button onClick={this.takeOwnership.bind(this)}>Take ownership !</button>
        <h3>{this.state.author}</h3>
        <p>{this.props.quote.text}</p>
      </li>
    );
  }
}
```

TLDR; I also find it confusing, it seems more like and advice, I recommend not putting too much attention on it, and to use hooks components, where you have more fined grained control, over props/state comparison and shallow/deep comparison.

Comment: Ambroise Rabier, When you say " When you put a parent as PureComponent, all the childrens become impacted." do you mean that because the parent does not re-render as a consequence neither do the children, right?

Comment: @DanielTinajeroDíaz Yes I am referring to "skips prop updates for the whole component subtree". It is demonstrated in `onClickIssue` function. Although the quote object reference changed, because the array containing it stay the same reference, and List is pure, it won't re-render ListElement.